# Setting headers in a HTTPC post request in Erlang

Tags: post, erlang, ejabberd

I am trying to fire a HTTPC post request from Erlang:

```
httpc:request(post, {"https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send",[{"Authorization","key=api_key_generated_at_googleaccount"}],[{"Content-Type","application/json"}],Body},[],[])
```

But every time I fire this request my Erlang shell hangs. Is there any problem in the request?

Answer (score 7):

I think you mixed up the arguments to `http:request/4` a bit, in the manual for [`httpc`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html):

```
request(Method, Request, HTTPOptions, Options)

   Request          = request()
   request()        = {url(), headers()} |
                      {url(), headers(), content_type(), body()}
   content_type()   = string()
```

Above you can see `content_type()` should be a `string()` and not `[{string(),string()}]`.

It is easier if to read if you put the whole `request()` into a variable:

```
10> inets:start().
ok
11> ssl:start().
ok
12> Body = "some cool json",
12> Request = {"https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send", [{"Authorization","key=blabla"}], "application/json", Body},
12> httpc:request(post, Request, [], []).
{ok,{{"HTTP/1.1",401,"Unauthorized"},
     [{"cache-control","private, max-age=0"},
      {"date","Tue, 03 Feb 2015 07:19:07 GMT"},
      {"accept-ranges","none"},
      {"server","GSE"},
      {"vary","Accept-Encoding"},
      {"content-length","147"},
      {"content-type","text/html; charset=UTF-8"},
      {"expires","Tue, 03 Feb 2015 07:19:07 GMT"},
      {"x-content-type-options","nosniff"},
      {"x-frame-options","SAMEORIGIN"},
      {"x-xss-protection","1; mode=block"},
      {"alternate-protocol","443:quic,p=0.02"}],
     "<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\" TEXT=\"#000000\">\n<H1>Unauthorized</H1>\n<H2>Error 401</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n"}}
```